# HTTP post request and save response in app

Tags: swift

I'm totally new to swift and iOS programming so I'm a little lost on how to do this and even in what files I should be doing this too.

I'm trying to do a http post request to get calendar events and save them in the app to later use and display.

I made a model class with this code.

```
import UIKit

class Event {
    var id: Int
    var init_date: String
    var end_date: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var color_code: String
    var all_day: Int
    
    
    init?(id: Int, init_date: String, end_date: String, title: String, description: String, color_code: String, all_day: Int) {
        
        //Initialization should fail if these are false
        if  id < 0 || init_date.isEmpty || end_date.isEmpty || title.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        
        //Initialize stored properties
        self.id = id
        self.init_date = init_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.color_code = color_code
        self.all_day = all_day
    }
}
```

But now I don't know what the next step would be. I need this to be downloaded immediately once the app is opened for the first time and not when it's not being opened for the first time. Do I create a new method in the ViewController.swift for the download?

Right now I haven't added anything to the ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

At this point you need to create a function that handles the POST request you are making.

Once completed, place this function inside your appDelegate main function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. This is the function that executes on appStart

On a successful function call save the data (presumably json) into a Global Variable or whatever you need for you app.

TIP:
On you class

```
class Event: Codable {

}
```

make sure to add Codable like above

Below is an example of what your post request will look like

```
    func myPostRequest(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool?, String?) -> Void){ 
guard let url = URL(string:"") else { return }
    
    let parameters = ["": ""]
    
    var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    do {
        
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            guard
                
                error == nil
                
            else {
                    
                print(error as Any)
                    
                return
                    
            }
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                
                if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                    
                    if let data = data {
                        
                        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
                        //print("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",json)
                        
                        
                        for x in json ?? [] {
                            //here is where you will parse your data from the post request
                            
                        }
                        
                        completionHandler(true, nil)
                        
                        return
                        
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    
                    completionHandler(false, "No Response From Server")
                    print("Failure response: STATUS CODE != 200")
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                
                completionHandler(false, "Database Connection Error")
                print("Error \(error!)")
                
            }
            
        }
        
        task.resume()
        
    } catch let error {
        
        completionHandler(false, "failure")
        print("POSTERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so a function something like this `func downloadData()`? What do I use to make the http post request?

Comment: @Nancy check my edits, above is a skeleton of a request that you can use.

Comment: I would add the code above in here?
`
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        //here?
        
        
        return true
    }
`

Comment: @Nancy what i have provided is a skeleton to get you started. If you are familiar with http requests you now need to fill in the skeleton. If you require more documentation i can provide you. Once you are successful in making a POST call , you then place this function call in appDelegate, didFinishLaunching. Generally within the function call you append the data to a Global variable, but this varies depending on your needs

Comment: ok, I only have a url and don't need any parameters, and as far as I know I don't need any headers but I'll leave them just in case. How can I then save each Event ? Do I need to create a database ?

Comment: @Nancy , it sounds like you need to read some documentation on URL Requests on swift.  here is something to get you started. https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227548/discussion-between-nancy-and-julian-silvestri).

Answer (score 0):

I use `Alamofire`, you can add it to your project via:

1. Pods
2. Swift Package Manager

When you add the framework you can use it:

```
import Alamofire
```

Then you need to make your class with the protocol `Codable` to pass the data to your class.

```
class Event: Codable { }
```

Then you need to call the `url` and store the response in a variable:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        AF.request("your API rest url").responseData { (resData) in
            guard let data = resData.data else { return }//Check if the data is valid
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()//Initialize a Json decoder variable
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Event.self, from: data)//Decode the response data to your decodable class
                //Print the values
                print(decodedData.headers)
                print(decodedData.id)
                print(decodedData.init_date)
                print(decodedData.end_date)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: while this is a valid answer, I would always recommend not using frameworks. Swift has an excellent foundation for handling http requests.